# How can I order alphabetically my LocalizedStringKey values?

Tags: enums, localization, swiftui

I have an enumeration of Countries, that return isoCodes, dialCodes and names. When inferring isoCodes and dialCodes, it works well, because they are String values. But when I am trying to map the LocalizeStringKey of the names, and have them in alphabetical order, the keys only are set in order, but not the translation, which is an issue.

How can I retrieve my enumeration countries' names, set as LocalizedStringKey, in an alphabetical order using SwiftUI?

This is what I am trying to do...

The way that I am trying to map in the right order the countries names in my files:
(Only getting the localized key in order)

```
let countries = Country.allCases.map { $0 }
```

My Country enum:

```
import SwiftUI

// MARK: Country ISO3166 definition
enum Country: String, CaseIterable {

  case ad
  case ae
  case af
  case ag
  case ai
  case al
}
```

My Countries name set as a variable:

```
// MARK: Country named from localized CountryString
extension Country {

  var name: CountryString {

    switch self {
    case .ad: return .andorra
    case .ae: return .unitedArabEmirates
    case .af: return .afghanistan
    case .ag: return .antiguaBarbuda
    case .ai: return .anguilla
    case .al: return .albania
   }
}
```

My CountryString enum where the localizedStringKey are set:

```
// MARK: Country string name
enum CountryString: LocalizedStringKey {

  case andorra
  case unitedArabEmirates
  case afghanistan
  case antiguaBarbuda
  case anguilla
  case albania
}
```

My translations:

```
// MARK: - CountryString
"andorra" = "Andorra";
"unitedArabEmirates" = "United Arab Emirates";
"afghanistan" = "Afghanistan";
"antiguaBarbuda" = "Antiga & Barbuda";
"anguilla" = "Anguilla";
"albania" = "Albania";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string interpolation, for example:

```
let countries = Country.allCases.map { $0 }

let cname = countries[x].name

let tname = NSLocalizedString("\(cname)", comment: "xxxx")
```

then sort them out alphabetically on translated name.